# @Html.EnumDropDownListFor ASP.Net set default as second member of enum

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums

This is my enum

```
 public enum UserStatus
    {
        Employee = 0,
        Evaluation,
        Dismissed, 
        Registered,
    }
```

And i have a EnumDropDownListFor for it

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.User.Metadata.Status)
```

And as default (when page had been loaded) i see Employee in this form.But i want to see firstly Evaluation.My first decision was changing enum query to

```
 public enum UserStatus
    {
        Evaluation = 0,
        Employee,
        Dismissed, 
        Registered,
    }
```

But it was bad decision for whole project(but working).So how easly i can set another default?Any ideas?

Comment: Set `model.User.Metadata.Status = UserStatus.Evaluation` in your action. It then should then be selected in your form.

Comment: If i do that in my controller,i will be able choose only Evaluation,or not?where i should write it?

Comment: You are setting the default, put it in your GET action method. However, if you are using this same method to "update" an existing user than you will have apply this default when you "new" up a new user instead.